# Registering UITableView cells in a loop through enum values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Registration of cells usually occurs in a static way.

Element types UITableViewCell:

```
enum CustomElementType: String {
    case header
    case field
    case picker
    case toggle
    case datePicker
}
```

Register cells:

```
tableView.register(CollapsibleTableViewHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: CustomElementType.header.rawValue)
tableView.register(FieldViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomElementType.field.rawValue)
tableView.register(PickerViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomElementType.picker.rawValue)
tableView.register(ToggleViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomElementType.toggle.rawValue)
tableView.register(DatePickerViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomElementType.datePicker.rawValue)
```

I want to register them in a loop, an approximate statement:

```
[FieldViewCell.self, PickerViewCell.self, ToggleViewCell.self, DatePickerViewCell.self].forEach { (GenericViewCell) in
    tableView.register(GenericViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: ?)
}
```

I assume that the following structure is needed to solve the problem:

```
struct Register {
    let cell: UITableViewCell
    let type: CustomElementType
}
```

And something like this register cells:

```
[Register(cell: FieldViewCell.self, type: .field), Register(cell: PickerViewCell.self, type: .picker), Register(cell: ToggleViewCell.self, type: .toggle), Register(cell: DatePickerViewCell.self, type: .datePicker)].forEach { (RegisterView) in
    tableView.register(RegisterView.cell, forCellReuseIdentifier: RegisterView.type.rawValue)
}
```

I get the following warning:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I want to get the best solution to this issue.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do it that way other than as intellectual exercise? It doesn't seem to improve code readability?

Comment: I have several types of cells for "UITableView", I adhere to simple, clear, compact (without duplication) code. I'm used to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
extension UITableView {

    func registerCells(_ types: [(AnyObject.Type, String)]) {
        for (type, identifier) in types {
            self.register(type, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }
    }

    func registerHeaderFooterViews(_ types: [(AnyObject.Type, String)]) {
        for (type, identifier) in types {
            self.register(type, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }
    }

}
```

example:

```
class FirstCell: UITableViewCell { /*code*/ }
class SecondCell: UITableViewCell { /*code*/ }

class FooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView { /*code*/ }

tableView.registerCells([
    (FirstCell.self, "identifierOfFirstCell"),
    (SecondCell.self, "identifierOfSecondCell")
])

tableView.registerHeaderFooterViews([
    (FooterView.self, "identifierOfFooterView")
])
```